# Trouble in using Bootstrap and Rails - Radio Button not working properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button, toggle

I have a trouble in using using bootstrap in Rails.

When I run the following codes, I am able to select a radio button only once.

```
var ss = "<form accept-charset='UTF-8' action='/add_funds' \
class='simple_form new_fund' id='new_fund' method='post' \
novalidate='novalidate'> \
<input class='radio_buttons optional' id='fund_amount_1' name='fund[amount]' type='radio' value='1' /> \
<input class='radio_buttons optional' id='fund_amount_2' name='fund[amount]' type='radio' value='2' /> \
<input class='radio_buttons optional' id='fund_amount_3' name='fund[amount]' type='radio' value='3' /> \
<input class='radio_buttons optional' id='fund_amount_4' name='fund[amount]' type='radio' value='4' /> \
</form>";
$('.message-dialog-content').html(ss);
```

For more information, please refer this video link.

http://screencast.com/t/3D2Bxj6f37g

Is there any help?

Comment: Did you manage to fix it? I am experiencing something similar.

Comment: Yes, I did. That was because of jQuery version. I was using jQuery 1.9.1, and there was a minor change for some methods such as attr vs prop in jQuery. Here is a link so that you can refer. [Fixing a problem on using Rails and jQuery1.9.1](https://github.com/caarlos0/rails-bootstrap-toggle-buttons/commit/70f8c25cf52a1cf80785086d874605798c0655d1)

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this problem by myself. That was because of jQuery version. I was using jQuery 1.9.1, and there was a minor change for some methods such as attr vs prop in jQuery. Here is a link so that you can refer. [Fixing a problem on using Rails and jQuery1.9.1](https://github.com/caarlos0/rails-bootstrap-toggle-buttons/commit/70f8c25cf52a1cf80785086d874605798c0655d1)